# Which double pole breaker do I need?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I have a 240volt 25 amp ptac unit for heating and cooling my large shed.

I ran 10/2 wire to a 30 amp outlet because that is the plug on the end of the unit.

What size double pole breaker do I need to support this ptac unit?

Comment: Do you mean double _pole_?

Comment: What does the labeling &/or instructions of the "ptac unit" specify as "minimum circuit ampacity" and "maximum overcurrent protection"? Those are normally labelled right on the unit itself.

Answer (score 1):

If the unit provides a maximum size breaker or OCPD you can not go above that value. Since you state it is a 25 amp I would install a 30 amp breaker and things will normally work fine. If the FLA / RLA is the 25 amp value a standard 30 amp HACR rated breaker would be normal with 10 awg wires,
But wait the code book states 125% of a motor load, I agree but only 125% of the largest motor then 100% of the rest. Outside units have at least 2 motors and a crank case heater for the compressor so again we can not put a larger breaker on the system than it allows.

If only the operational value is all that is listed(rare)  I would use a 30 amp hacr listed breaker with the number 10 wire. If the unit trips I would increase the breaker size (yes this can be done for motor loads and the breaker is only allowed to be large enough to allow starting up to 250% of the full load current).

You did not mention if you were going to use a fused disconnect at the unit or just a disconnect?  The outside package units usually have a disconnect built in.

Comment: I called the manufacturer and it does require a 30 amp double pull breaker.